# New line is not in result of xml to csv

Tags: xml, xslt, wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to convert the XML data into CSV format by XSLT.When I am testing in XSLT tester its working proper but its not working in wso2.
Result is coming in one line instead of each records in new line.

XML Data

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soapenv:Body>
   <dbs:DBSelectResult xmlns:dbs="http://esb.agava.net/mediators/db/dbselect">
   <dbs:row>
        <dbs:NAME name="NAME">100000007</dbs:NAME>
        <dbs:TITLE__C name="TITLE__C">test</dbs:TITLE__C>
        <dbs:SHORT_DESCRIPTION__C name="SHORT_DESCRIPTION__C" />
     </dbs:row>
     <dbs:row>
        <dbs:NAME name="NAME">100000005</dbs:NAME>
        <dbs:TITLE__C name="TITLE__C">TEST4</dbs:TITLE__C>
        <dbs:SHORT_DESCRIPTION__C name="SHORT_DESCRIPTION__C">TEST4</dbs:SHORT_DESCRIPTION__C>
     </dbs:row>
   </dbs:DBSelectResult>
   </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
```

XSLT:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:dbs="http://esb.agava.net/mediators/db/dbselect" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1"></xsl:output>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"></xsl:strip-space>
    <xsl:template match="//dbs:DBSelectResult/dbs:row">
     <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
         <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
           <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"></xsl:value-of>',</xsl:if>

        <xsl:if test="position()  = last()">
          <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
           <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"></xsl:value-of>
           <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>

     </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:template>
     </xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I am saving this XSLT as localentry in wso2,amp;#xa; is getting lost due to which the result is coming in one line instead of each record in newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#xa` is lost if you use WSO2 Web Console : deploy this local-entry copying the file to repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/local-entries or deploying a carbon archive.